# How does ARP work when my ONU Modem is in bridge mode?

Tags: networking, router, mikrotik-routeros

How does ARP work when my ONU Modem is in bridge mode?

Bridge mode is transparent in Layer 2, it just forwards the frame unaltered coming from my ISP from my WAN port to my router.

Yeah I know that, but what I am trying to say is that the MAC address I am seeing at my ARP table in Mikrotik, is it the bridged MAC address WAN interface port bound to port 1? Or is it the ISP's optical line termination (OLT) MAC address?

In the ARP table, it contains a public IP gateway and a similar MAC address to my WAN Interface that I have cloned to (only the starting point xx: the other parts are very far from my WAN that I have cloned).